# Create a race timer using Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, timing

I am trying to create an online application for our canoe club that can be used to time races that we hold within our club . I am not very comfortable with javascript but assume that is the best way to go .

Can someone please make a suggestion on how I can do this or point me in the right direction . We basicaly need something that I can start a timer and as the kids come across the finish line press a button ( I would have already registered all the kids names into the race database ) and then the time for that kid would be recorded into the database , All I really need help with is the actual timing part .

Thanking you in advance for any suggestions or help .

Comment: JavaScript is most likely the way to go, check out the setTimeout() function.

Comment: There is also setInterval() which might be good for updating a UI if there is one.